# Python: Context manager with multiple objects?

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

Is it possible to use the `with` context manager syntax with more than one object in Python?

For example, something like:

```
with open("file1.txt") as file1, open("file2.txt") as file2:
    file1.write("this is file 1")
    file2.write("this is file 2")
```

A duckduckgo and internal search of this site indicates the answer is probably "no". Given that the likely answer is "no", what is the next best option? (Of course, if the answer is "yes", please let me know how.)

Perhaps a set of nexted context managers, such as the following, would be a good solution?

```
with open("file1.txt") as file1:
    with open("file2.txt") as file2:
        file1.write("this is file 1")
        file2.write("this is file 2")
```

Is there any reason why one would not want to do this? Is the order likely to matter?

Comment: The answer is yes, you can open multiple files in same line

Comment: Have you tried your first code sample? That **is** the way to do it

Comment: When `with` statements were added in Python 2.5, they were limited to a single context expression. Support for multiple context expressions was added in Python 3.1.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement

Answer (score 1):

This

```
with open("file1.txt") as file1, open("file2.txt") as file2:
    file1.write("this is file 1")
    file2.write("this is file 2")
```

is compliant with `with` statement definition given by [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

```
with_stmt ::=  "with" with_item ("," with_item)* ":" suite
with_item ::=  expression ["as" target]
```

where `*` denotes 0 or more repetitions

Comment: Nice to know my guess was correct, wasn't able to find an example of this